# Getting Bearer token scoped for Azure Graph and need Microsoft Graph

Tags: oauth

Using the below JS code to get Microsoft oAuth Bearer token, a get a token scoped to Azure Graph aud: '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' when I need Microsoft Graph which should be aud: '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'

I have the app registered with several Microsoft Graph admin consented permissions including:
MailboxSettings.ReadWrite & User.Read.All

Each call to Microsoft Graph using the token fails with 401 Unauthorized.

JS token fetch function:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
async function getToken() {
  // Construct the authorization token URL
  const tokenUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`;

  // Specify the scope for Microsoft Graph API
  const graphApiScope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';

  // Create a request body with token request parameters
  const tokenRequestParams = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: graphApiScope, // Use the explicitly defined scope
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  });

  try {
    // Request an access token using the client credentials
    const response = await fetch(tokenUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: tokenRequestParams,
    });

    const tokenResponse = await response.json();
    return tokenResponse.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Failed to obtain access token: ' + error.message);
  }
}
```

I've tried in Powershell, Node.js, and using the token in Postman, all with same results.  Postman response header indicates that indeed, the Microsoft Graph API is responding:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="**00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000**"
```

Comment: remember to actually read the tag descriptions BEFORE you add a tag.